# Extracting XML Data with Foreach Loops Based on a Specific Tag ID

Tags: php, arrays, xml, foreach, domdocument

I am trying to extract data from a XML document based on the value of a tag, `<styleId>`.

If the `<styleId> = 292015` I want the `value` data listed, similarly if `<styleId> = 292016` I want the `value` data listed. Here is an example:

```
<technicalSpecification>
  <titleId>6</titleId>
  <value value="All-Wheel Drive" condition="">
   <styleId>292015</styleId>
   <styleId>292016</styleId>
  </value>
</technicalSpecification>
```

So for the above if I were to call all `value` data containing `<styleId>292015</styleId>` I would receive `All-Wheel Drive`. Additionally, if I were to call all `value` data containing `<styleId>292016</styleId>`, I would also receive `All-Wheel Drive`.

Here is the full XML document I am pulling from.

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <S:Body>
  <VehicleDescription country="US" language="en" modelYear="2008" bestMakeName="Audi" bestModelName="S4" bestStyleName="5dr Avant Wgn" xmlns="urn:description7b.services.chrome.com">
     <responseStatus responseCode="Successful" description="Successful"/>

     <style id="292015" modelYear="2008" name="5dr Avant Wgn Man" nameWoTrim="5dr Avant Wgn Man" mfrModelCode="8ED549" fleetOnly="false" modelFleet="false" passDoors="4" altBodyType="Station Wagon" drivetrain="All Wheel Drive">
        <division id="4">Audi</division>
        <subdivision id="5020">Audi</subdivision>
        <model id="17308">S4</model>
        <basePrice unknown="false" invoice="46137.0" msrp="49610.0" destination="775.0"/>
        <bodyType primary="true" id="7">Station Wagon</bodyType>
        <marketClass id="53">Small Wagon</marketClass>
        <acode>USB80AUC085A0</acode>
     </style>
     <style id="292016" modelYear="2008" name="5dr Avant Wgn Auto" nameWoTrim="5dr Avant Wgn Auto" mfrModelCode="8ED54L" fleetOnly="false" modelFleet="false" passDoors="4" altBodyType="Station Wagon" drivetrain="All Wheel Drive">
        <division id="4">Audi</division>
        <subdivision id="5020">Audi</subdivision>
        <model id="17308">S4</model>
        <basePrice unknown="false" invoice="47162.0" msrp="50710.0" destination="775.0"/>
        <bodyType primary="true" id="7">Station Wagon</bodyType>
        <marketClass id="53">Small Wagon</marketClass>
        <acode>USB80AUC085A1</acode>
     </style>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>1</titleId>
        <value value="Audi S4" condition="-PT">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
        <value value="Audi S4" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>2</titleId>
        <value value="5 Door Wagon" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>6</titleId>
        <value value="All-Wheel Drive" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>7</titleId>
        <value value="Small Station Wagon" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>8</titleId>
        <range min="5.0" max="5.0"/>
        <value value="5" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>9</titleId>
        <range min="90.8" max="90.8"/>
        <value value="90.8" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>10</titleId>
        <range min="4012.0" max="4101.0"/>
        <value value="4012" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
        </value>
        <value value="4101" condition="">
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>26</titleId>
        <range min="13.0" max="14.0"/>
        <value value="13" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
        </value>
        <value value="14" condition="">
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>27</titleId>
        <range min="20.0" max="21.0"/>
        <value value="20" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
        </value>
        <value value="21" condition="">
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>31</titleId>
        <value value="- TBD -" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>32</titleId>
        <value value="- TBD -" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>33</titleId>
        <value value="- TBD -" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>34</titleId>
        <value value="- TBD -" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>40</titleId>
        <value value="" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>41</titleId>
        <value value="Gas V8" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>42</titleId>
        <value value="4.2L/254" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>43</titleId>
        <value value="SEFI" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>48</titleId>
        <value value="340 @ 6800" condition="">
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
        <value value="340 @ 7000" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>49</titleId>
        <value value="302 @ 3500" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>51</titleId>
        <value value="" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>52</titleId>
        <range min="6.0" max="6.0"/>
        <value value="6" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>53</titleId>
        <value value="Manual" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
        </value>
        <value value="Automatic" condition="">
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>54</titleId>
        <value value="" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>56</titleId>
        <range min="3.67" max="4.17"/>
        <value value="3.67" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
        </value>
        <value value="4.17" condition="">
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>57</titleId>
        <range min="2.05" max="2.34"/>
        <value value="2.05" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
        </value>
        <value value="2.34" condition="">
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>58</titleId>
        <range min="1.46" max="1.52"/>
        <value value="1.46" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
        </value>
        <value value="1.52" condition="">
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>59</titleId>
        <range min="1.13" max="1.14"/>
        <value value="1.13" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
        </value>
        <value value="1.14" condition="">
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
  </VehicleDescription>
```

Here is some of my current PHP:

```
<?php

  $xml = file_get_contents('data.xml');
  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  $dom->loadXML($xml);

?>

<?php


 foreach ( $dom->getElementsByTagName('technicalSpecification') as $techSpec )   {
  if ($techSpec->getElementsByTagName('styleId')->item(0)->nodeValue == '292015'){
  $techDatass = $techSpec->getElementsByTagName('value')->item(0)->getAttribute("value");
  $techData[] = $techDatass;
  }
 }
 foreach ($techData as $finalTech){
  echo $finalTech."<br>";
 }

 echo "<br><br>";

?>
```

This returns most value data containing `<styleId>292015</styleId>`. However it does not return all value data tied to that tag. Additionally, if I plug `292016` into it, it only returns one value. I believe this is because of `item(0)`. I am not sure how to structure the loop so that if `292016` comes after `292015` it will still recognize that and display the `value` data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @nigelren any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just stick with DOMDocument you could add some nested loops:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$techData = [];

foreach ( $dom->getElementsByTagName('technicalSpecification') as $techSpecElement )   {
    foreach($techSpecElement->getElementsByTagName('value') as $valueElement) {
        foreach($valueElement->getElementsByTagName('styleId') as $styleIdElement) {
            // check the value of the styleId here
            if (in_array($styleIdElement->nodeValue, ['292015','292016'])) {
                // if it matches, get the parent value element's value
                $techData[] = $valueElement->getAttribute("value");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem. DOMXPath is very powerful too but sometimes it's easiest to just loop through the DOM especially if the XML structure is somewhat simple.

Comment: I think I might transfer my code over to DOMXPath. Everyone is suggesting I do so.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DOMXPath`

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

// We starts from the root element
$query = '//value/styleId';
$entries = $xpath->query($query);

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $styleId = $entry->nodeValue;
    $value = $entry->parentNode->attributes->getNamedItem("value");
    echo "$styleId -> $value\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! It is not working for me. See here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7fd7b8bdd8a843172c35ce79c4bca17db338d9b3

Comment: You still have to create a `DOMDocument` as in your original code.

Comment: Still no result after creating a `DOMDocument`. See here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/25f8bf7cbef54ad57c5c169eb08e4314ac43f937

Comment: The XML document you are using the in the linked code doesn't match your question so you have to adjust the xpath query.

Comment: I copy and pasted it from this question.